# Drawing with a different point of view

Tags: c, opengl, view, point

If I draw a cube on the center of my window, I can see only the front side. (OK)

When I draw a cube on the bottom right side of my window, I see the front, top and left sides of the cube. (OK)

I want to draw the cube on the bottom right side of the window but as my eyes where on the bottom right side (I want to see only the front side of the cube).

I've tried to use gluLookat, but it just moved the cube to the center of the window. (As I didn't use `glTranslatef`)

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the viewport to cover only the bottom right side of the window and draw the cube "in the center".

Comment: It was a lot simpler than I tought! Thanks ;)